# Ruby: Cannot Delete Element from Array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am having trouble deleting an element from an array at the line

```
array1.delete_at(i)
```

I believe I am following the instructions [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html), but I am getting a weird "No Implicit Conversion of String to Integer" Error.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
def calc(input)
    stack = []
    array1 = input.split(//)   #// splits into individual characters
    array1.each do |i|
        if i.match(/[0-9]/) then
            stack.push(i.to_i)
            puts "\n" ; print stack
            array1.delete_at(i)
            puts "\n" ; print array1
        end
    end
end

string = calc('123456')
puts string
```

Comment: For quick debugging: `p stack` or `p array1`.

Answer (score 0):

`i` is a string, even if it contains a digit

Try this one

```
array1.delete_at(i.to_i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `each_with_index` rather than `each`, so you can pass that index value to `delete_at`. Currently you're passing a number from `input` as the index you want to delete from the string, which doesn't seem like what you'd want.

I think the following will work for you:

```
def calc(input)
  stack = []
  array1 = input.split(//)
  array1.each_with_index do |num, i|
    if num.match(/[0-9]/) then
        stack.push(num.to_i)
        puts; print stack
        array1.delete_at(i) # passing the index rather than num now
        puts; print array1
    end
  end
end
```

Note that I changed `puts "\n"` to `puts`, because `puts` will add a newline when called without arguments.

Comment: Thanks Gary.  I tried your code, but Delete, removes every object from the array that matches the value.  I only want to remove that particular value!

Answer (score 0):

As the other poster noted, `i` is a string. Do this instead:

```
array1 = input.split(//).map(&:to_i)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I like where you're going that seems more efficient.  However, I am getting an error now from that syntax.     22:in `block in calc': undefined method `match' for 1:Integer (NoMethodError)

Comment: `Integer` does not have a function called `match`. Those are for strings only. I didn't know what `input` looked like when I wrote this. I would use Ursus solution for your use case.